# Bootstrap 5 Mobile Navigation Bar Not Expanding

Tags: html, css, navbar, bootstrap-5

I'm making my first webpage and wanted to include a responsive navigation bar with Bootstrap 5.
I had it working for a while and as I was going about my business I realized the bar had stopped working.
Currently it works in the "large" web view as intended but once I decrease screen size it ceases to function. The button itself 'clicks' but the header doesnt expand downward
Here's the code for the drop down as well as the CSS for the header area and responsive rules
Thanks so much!!

HTML

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-body-secondary rounded-4">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Kumi Sushi</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button> 
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="menu.html">Menu</a>
        </li>
              <!-- dropdown -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Navigation
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="directions.html">Directions</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>  
              <!-- dropdown -->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- Navbar -->  


>>>>>CSS 

  /* HEADER */
  header {
      background: 
          /* top, transparent black, faked with gradient */ 
          linear-gradient(
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 
              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
          ),
      url(Images/hero.jpg);
      background-position: center;
      background-size: 100%;
      height: 400px;
      padding: 20px; 
      text-align: center;
    } 
    header .logo a { 
        background-image: url("Images/logo.png"); 
        background-size: 280px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        display: inline-block; 
        height: 340px;
        width: 280px;
        top: 0rem;
        position: relative; 
        text-align: center;
        text-indent: -999999999px;
    }  
    
     .navbar { 
        background-color: gray;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #777; 
        height: rem;
     } 
     .navbar-brand { 
        text-transform:uppercase; 
     }
    nav ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    } 
      nav li { 
          color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
          font-size: larger; 
          font-weight: 400;
          display: inline-flex; 
          justify-content: center;
          margin-right: 20px; 
          border-radius: 2px; 
          padding: 2px; 
    } 
      section {
        background: white;
        padding: 20px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }  
  

/* RESPONSIVE RULES .IMG */
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
        header { 
                height: 200px; 
                background-position: 0 -0px; 
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 548px) { 
        nav li { 
            font-size: medium;
      } 
    }    
    @media screen and (max-width: 625px) {
        .features { 
            display: block;
        } 
        }  
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
        .navbar { 
            height: 3.2rem; 
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 859px) { 
        header .logo a {
            background-image: url("Images/logo.png"); 
            text-align: center; 
            background-size: 58%; 
            background-position: 50% 0;
        } 
        header { 
            height: 220px; 
            background-position: 0 0px;
        } 
    }
```

I tried pasting the code back in, making sure I was using v5.3, and tried getting rid of anything I had edited in style.css

So far in the developer tools it shows the drop-down items centered and behind the logo.
I tested the HTML without the style sheet and it worked as intended, I'm wondering if there's a common issue I may be overlooking here.

I was messing around in the style sheet when I had noticed the problem, I went back and deleted all uncommited changes and I'm still at a loss.
I spent the last hour and a half digging through the Bootstrap website to find anything regarding problems that might arise with this, as well as looking at some old questions on here and couldn't find my solution.
The solution is probably pretty obvious but definitely over my head lmao

Also a note, I have my Bootstrap CSS CDN in my  and the JS CDN at the end of the . Looks like most of the old responses were due to not having jQuery in the right place, but it doesnt look like I need it for 5.3

Any advice is appreciated! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Page:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

because It's working in codepen.